# Exporting data from Matlab (.mat file) into an existing Excel sheet at a specific range

Tags: excel, matlab

the following Matlab script creates a .mat file. which has multiple cases. Each case has different outputs. I run this script multiple times and store the output manually in an excel sheet [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sPBg.jpg). For example, after running the script for 1st time i save the output under the column Run1 and after second in Run2. Starting from Run 3, I want to have matlab to export the results from .mat file without entering them  manually.

Note: The only values that change are the output values for each run. Rest will be same for every run.

```matlab
%% Example of how the data is structured

% initialize testSetup
testSetup = struct( ...
    'name', {'01_Case1', '01_Case2', '01_Case3' , ...
              '02_Case1', '02_Case2','02_Case3','02_Case4' ...
              '03_Case1','03_Case2','03_Case3',...
              '04_Case1','04_Case2'}, ...
     'rollno',  {struct, struct, struct,struct, struct, struct,struct,...
                struct, struct,struct, struct, struct},...
     'subject', {struct, struct, struct,struct, struct, struct,struct,...
                struct, struct,struct, struct, struct},...
    'evaluation',{struct, struct, struct,struct, struct, struct,struct,...
                struct, struct,struct, struct, struct});
%input the data
testSetup(1).evaluation.output1.result=0.1; 
testSetup(1).evaluation.output2.result=0.2;
testSetup(1).evaluation.output3.result=0.3;
testSetup(2).evaluation.output1.result=0.1;
testSetup(2).evaluation.output2.result=0.2;
testSetup(2).evaluation.output3.result=0.3;
testSetup(2).evaluation.output4.result=0.4;
testSetup(3).evaluation.output1.result=0.1;
testSetup(3).evaluation.output2.result=0.2;
testSetup(3).evaluation.output3.result=0.3;
testSetup(4).evaluation.output1.result=0.1;
testSetup(4).evaluation.output2.result=0.2;
testSetup(5).evaluation.output1.result=0.1; 
testSetup(5).evaluation.output2.result=0.2;
testSetup(5).evaluation.output3.result=0.3;
testSetup(6).evaluation.output1.result=0.1;
testSetup(6).evaluation.output2.result=0.2;
testSetup(6).evaluation.output3.result=0.3;
testSetup(7).evaluation.output1.result=0.1;
testSetup(7).evaluation.output2.result=0.2;
testSetup(7).evaluation.output3.result=0.3;
testSetup(8).evaluation.output1.result=0.1;
testSetup(8).evaluation.output2.result=0.2;
testSetup(9).evaluation.output1.result=0.1;
testSetup(9).evaluation.output2.result=0.2;
testSetup(9).evaluation.output3.result=0.3;
testSetup(10).evaluation.output1.result=0.1;
testSetup(10).evaluation.output2.result=0.2;
testSetup(11).evaluation.output1.result=0.1;
testSetup(11).evaluation.output2.result=0.2;
testSetup(11).evaluation.output3.result=0.3;
testSetup(12).evaluation.output1.result=0.1;
testSetup(12).evaluation.output2.result=0.2;
%save as .mat
save testsetup.mat
```

Comment: add your Matlab script please

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways you can do this.

First, let's define the data. It's not 100% clear from your question how your data is structured, so you will have to get it into this format.

```
header = {'Exp1', 'Exp2', 'Exp3'};

case1 = { ...
    'class1', 90, 91;
    'class2', 91, 91;
    'class3', 92, 91;
    'class4', 93, 91;
    };
case2 = { ...
    'class1', 90, 92;
    'class2', 91, 92;
    'class3', 92, 92;
    };
case3 = { ...
    'class1', 90, 93;
    'class2', 91, 93;
    'class3', 92, 93;
    };
case4 = { ...
    'class1', 90, 90;
    'class2', 91, 90;
    'class3', 92, 90;
    };
```

The first method writes each component separately, to sheet `Sheet1`:

```
xlswrite('temp.xlsx', header, 'Sheet1', 'B1');
xlswrite('temp.xlsx', {'Case1'}, 'Sheet1', 'A2');
xlswrite('temp.xlsx', case1, 'Sheet1', 'A3');
xlswrite('temp.xlsx', {'Case2'}, 'Sheet1', 'A8');
xlswrite('temp.xlsx', case2, 'Sheet1', 'A9');
xlswrite('temp.xlsx', {'Case3'}, 'Sheet1', 'A13');
xlswrite('temp.xlsx', case3, 'Sheet1', 'A14');
xlswrite('temp.xlsx', {'Case4'}, 'Sheet1', 'A18');
xlswrite('temp.xlsx', case4, 'Sheet1', 'A19');
```

The second method writes the whole thing in one write operation, to sheet `Sheet2`, producing equivalent output:

```
blank_row = repmat({NaN}, 1, 4);
C = cat(1, ...
    cat(2, {NaN}, header), ...
    {'Case1', NaN, NaN, NaN}, ...
    cat(2, case1, repmat({NaN}, size(case1, 1), 1)), ...
    blank_row, ...
    {'Case2', NaN, NaN, NaN}, ...
    cat(2, case2, repmat({NaN}, size(case2, 1), 1)), ...
    blank_row, ...
    {'Case3', NaN, NaN, NaN}, ...
    cat(2, case3, repmat({NaN}, size(case3, 1), 1)), ...
    blank_row, ...
    {'Case4', NaN, NaN, NaN}, ...
    cat(2, case4, repmat({NaN}, size(case4, 1), 1)));
xlswrite('temp.xlsx', C, 'Sheet2');
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot add the Matlab script here, What if i have  20 outputs. Do i have to write the code which you wrote for 20 outputs? or is there any other way? Thank you.

Comment: Can you kindly share MATLAB code that reproduces your structure array? There is certainly a way to automate the production of the cell arrays to write to Excel (such as by calling `fieldnames` on your structure array and iterating).

Comment: I can't find a way to add it here because of 2 reasons. 1. The script uses multiple function files to get the final result and 2. i cannot disclose it. That being said I will try to access the output from the .mat file which is being stored and add them case by case to the specific row and column. But i believe it will be a bit long.

Comment: Hm, can you reproduce something like it using the struct command and assignment? For example, `s = struct; s.Case1.class1 = 90; s.Case1.class2 = 91; s.Case2.class1 = 90;` - does this give something that is in the same format?

Comment: Yes, it's almost similar. There are a few changes, so i created a testSetup.mat file and attached 3 pictures above. Please follow them in order to get the idea. After seeing them, as you can see in pic 3 there is output with value 0.2550. Thats what I need to export into the excel sheet into a specific row and column. (Also, there are around 20 Cases, like Case1,Cas2...Case20. The size of the testSetup is 1*26).

Comment: Thank you for sharing. Just added a new answer since it's so different from this one given the structure of the data. In the future, I'd recommend trying to produce a reproducible example - i.e. provide the sample data yourself. This will ensure that the answer is applicable to your specific situation.

Comment: ohh...Sorry this is my first ever question here. I will keep that in mind from next time.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the pictures you provided, it appears your data is structured something like the following (sample data based on your picture). This of course wouldn't have to be coded manually - the instances of `testSetup` would come from your script, and you would just have to append them onto `experiment`.

If your data is differently structured, you may need to adjust the code below a bit. However, the changes shouldn't be too significant.

```
%% Create sample data

% initialize testSetup
testSetup = struct( ...
    'name', {'Case1', 'Case2', 'Case3'}, ...
    'A', {struct, struct, struct}, ...
    'B', {struct, struct, struct}, ...
    'C', {struct, struct, struct});

% assume there are two experiments
experiment = struct('testSetup', {testSetup, testSetup});

% sample data for experiment 1
experiment(1).testSetup(1).C.class1.output = 90;
experiment(1).testSetup(1).C.class2.output = 91;
experiment(1).testSetup(1).C.class3.output = 92;
experiment(1).testSetup(1).C.class4.output = 93;
experiment(1).testSetup(2).C.class1.output = 90;
experiment(1).testSetup(2).C.class2.output = 91;
experiment(1).testSetup(2).C.class3.output = 92;
experiment(1).testSetup(3).C.class1.output = 90;
experiment(1).testSetup(3).C.class2.output = 91;
experiment(1).testSetup(3).C.class3.output = 92;
experiment(1).testSetup(4).C.class1.output = 90;
experiment(1).testSetup(4).C.class2.output = 91;
experiment(1).testSetup(4).C.class3.output = 92;

% sample data for experiment 2
experiment(2).testSetup(1).C.class1.output = 91;
experiment(2).testSetup(1).C.class2.output = 91;
experiment(2).testSetup(1).C.class3.output = 91;
experiment(2).testSetup(1).C.class4.output = 91;
experiment(2).testSetup(2).C.class1.output = 92;
experiment(2).testSetup(2).C.class2.output = 92;
experiment(2).testSetup(2).C.class3.output = 92;
experiment(2).testSetup(3).C.class1.output = 93;
experiment(2).testSetup(3).C.class2.output = 93;
experiment(2).testSetup(3).C.class3.output = 93;
experiment(2).testSetup(4).C.class1.output = 90;
experiment(2).testSetup(4).C.class2.output = 90;
experiment(2).testSetup(4).C.class3.output = 90;
```

Now that we have data, we can write it to Excel. Our plan will be to write it to a cell array, one experiment at a time.

This code assumes that `testSetup` is similarly structured for each experiment. In particular, it assumes that the case names are the same for each experiment, and that within each case the classes are the same. These two assumptions are explicitly checked in the code.

```
%% Output to Excel

% CREATE CELL TO WRITE TO FILE (cell_to_write)

% initialize to overall header row
cell_to_write = cat(2, {NaN}, ...
    cellfun(@(x)sprintf('Exp%d', x), num2cell(1 : length(experiment)), 'UniformOutput', false));

% names of cases
case_names = experiment(1).testSetup(casenum).name;
% ... check that each experiment has the same cases
for expnum = 1 : length(experiment)
    if ~isequal(case_names, experiment(expnum).testSetup(casenum).name)
        error('Cases are different for different experiments');
    end
end

% create remainder of cell
for casenum = 1 : length(experiment(1).testSetup) % iterate over cases

    % header row for current case
    curr_header = cat(2, ...
        {case_names}, ...
        repmat({NaN}, 1, length(experiment)));

    % classes within current case
    curr_classes = fieldnames(experiment(1).testSetup(casenum).C);

    % body for current case
    % ... write names of classes
    curr_body = cat(2, ...
        curr_classes, ...
        repmat({NaN}, length(curr_classes), length(experiment)));
    % ... write numeric data
    for expnum = 1 : length(experiment) % iterate over experiments
        % check that each experiment has the same classes for the current case
        if ~isequal(curr_classes, fieldnames(experiment(expnum).testSetup(casenum).C))
            error('Classes are different for different experiments');
        end
        for classnum = 1 : length(curr_classes)
            curr_body{classnum, expnum + 1} = ...
                experiment(expnum).testSetup(casenum).C.(curr_classes{classnum}).output;
        end
    end

    % append current case to cell
    cell_to_write = cat(1, ...
        cell_to_write, ...
        curr_header, ...                            % current header
        curr_body, ...                              % current body
        repmat({NaN}, 1, size(cell_to_write, 2)));  % blank row
end

% WRITE TO FILE

xlswrite('temp.xlsx', cell_to_write, 'Sheet1');
```

Comment: Hi, I am working on this one with parallel to a main project. (I have to integrate this into the main project). I will definitely post my update here. Sorry it takes long and Thank you very much.

Comment: Great! No rush from my side of course, just making sure you have the help you need!

Comment: Hi, I started working on the problem and I have a few questions. 1. You mentioned about appending the data from testsetup onto expriment but i think that seems like a long process (I may be wrong) because i have more than 26cases. 2. In the script "output to excel" what are the "casenum". I am sorry if am not being able to convey my questions clearly. Should i create another thread to explains the problem (which includes my code that creates the .mat file)? Thank you very much.

Comment: (1) Something similar to the code in this answer should work for any number of cases - it doesn't matter if it's 3 or 26. (2) `casenum` is a variable used to iterate over the cases - it is calculated on the line `for casenum = 1 : length(experiment(1).testSetup) % iterate over cases` (see MATLAB documentation for `for`: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/for.html). (3) You can edit your original question to include your code to create the .mat file - that is much better than creating a new question, to keep StackOverflow clean.

Comment: I have edited the question. I apologize if it looks totally like a different question. This is my first ever question asking on the internet. So having a hard time explaining it. Thanks for understanding.

Answer (score 0):

> So, how I solved it was to find the size of my dataset (.mat file) and iterate over the number of cases, and accessing the output with respect to each case, and then converting it into an array so that it can be easily copied to an excel sheet.
>
> Note: If there is a scenario where the case values are empty, then you can use a for loop to check empty values and replace those with NaN.

```
sz = size(testsetup,2);
exportArr=[];

% Converting to an array and transposing it to make it a column and later on copying 
% it into an Excel Sheet.

for i = 1:sz
    str = struct2array(testSetup(i).evaluation); 
    data = struct2array(str);
    exportArr = [exportArr;nan;data'];
end
```